# Resftul Api with NodeJS for Mobile Application And 3rd Party Applications

Tags: node.js, api, express, oauth, passport.js

I am developing a Restful API with NodeJS which will service to a specific mobile application and (maybe in future) other 3rd party applications.

After some search I decided to use ExpressJS for middleware, Mongoose for mongo-related operations and PassportJS for authentication while developing API.

But there are still questions in my mind about infrastructure and i hope you can enlight me.

1. How should i secure my API? Firstly I thought, I can secure all API endpoints with OAuth; but if use OAuth, how Mobile Application use API?
2. Because of first question, I thought; I should develop two API's. One private API for Mobile Application; and one public API for 3rd Applications. Should I?
3. This is my first NodeJS application so I read lots of things about it. But all of them seems to be written for "Hello World" examples. Is there any articles or tutorials really helps me to develop real world application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1 and 2

OAuth (2) can be a good option, and you can safely use it for internal and external apps too. The same author as PassportJS created also [OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize), an OAuth2 server that works very nicely with PassportJS.
Using OAuth2 is safe and reliable, and there are plenty of third party libraries that you and other persons may use.
However...

1. Using OAuth2 usually requires users to authenticate every time. If you add a "remember my password" feature in the login page, users are not required to type their password again, but a web frame needs to be opened anyway.
   A possible solution would be to use auth tokens with a long expiration (if ever expiring), but you need to make sure they are transferred and stored safely. Usually users always get a short-living token, which can then be exchanged for a long-living one. The reason for this is to avoid sending long-living tokens in the response URL (only option if you're creating a mobile app). The request for exchanging short-living tokens for long-living ones usually needs to be signed with an app secret to add more security (albeit in mobile apps it's never possible to fully protect app secret keys).
2. Having two different authentication systems could be an option. It is certainly easier (if it allows you to delay the implementation of OAuth2), more integrated in your app (you don't need to load a web view to let users sign in) and still equally safe. You will have a form in your app that asks for username and password and sends it to the server. The server then responds with an "access token" which has a very long (if any) expiration date.

Of course, you should make sure that **ALL** API calls are made through SSL. Not only when you send passwords, but any following request too, since you'll be sending access tokens (which are "like passwords" for the session - that never expires).

### Question 3

PassportJS has [some great example code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples) that will also allow you to get a start, not just with PassportJS but also with Node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but firstly i want to ask your opinions about OAuth2? At the begining i was thinking to use OAuth2 but after reading this http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/ i gave up.

Comment: @bahadirarslan All major companies worldwide are adopting OAuth2, from Facebook to Google. The specs are clear and well-thought, and, as that article itself says, they're safe. His critic focuses mostly on possible bad implementations from 3rd parties. If you stick to public, tested libraries and you think about what you're doing, I doubt you'll have any problem.